# Specify -output-directory when using latexmk

Tags: latexmk, output, build-system

I am using `latexmk` for the automatic resolution of needed reruns. I would like to put all build files (aux, log, bbl, pdf, etc.) in a subdirectory.

I cannot find an option for latexmk to do this. If I specify `-output-directory` in the pdflatex rule like this

```
$pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=build";
```

latexmk fails to find the files when doing a second run.

Has anyone found a suitable solution?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use latexmk's `-jobname` option like this:

```
latexmk -pdf -jobname=path/to/new/output/newfilename currentfile
```

and all of the output files will be routed to the directory specified and given the basename 'newfilename'. E.g., all the files associated with processing currentfile.tex will now be in path/to/new/output/ and be called newfilename.pdf, newfilename.bbl, etc.
Mind that only relative paths work for security reasons (see comments).

Comment: Works nicely if a relative path is passed to -jobname. If an absolute path is used the following message from pdflatex crops up: `pdflatex: Not writing to /full/path/build/out.aux (openout_any = p).`

Comment: Aha ... I tested it on a relative path (within the current directory) so I missed that.

Comment: The failure with absolute paths is for [security reasons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12417/texify-and-output-directory/12453#12453).  You can always use a local symlink pointing to the global directory though.

Comment: I've tried this and I still get a <filename>.aux file for all tex files that are included in the main.tex file.

Answer (score 39):

As announced at [Use MiKTeX option through latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30350/use-miktex-option-through-latexmk/31252#31252), I've made a new version of latexmk, which supports `-output-directory`.  It's v. 4.27a and can be found at
http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/versions.html  (It'll be on CTAN soon.)

Just use the following settings in your `latexmkrc` file

```
$pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S";
$out_dir = 'build';
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Dec. 2011 with both MiKTeX and TeXLive you can use

**-outdir=FOO or -output-directory=FOO**

like so:

```
latexmk -output-directory="../out"
```

Source: http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf