# Texify and `--output-directory`

Tags: miktex, folders, output, options, texify

I'd like to tell `texify` to place compiled output (i.e., `.pdf` in my case) in the parent directory (I'm using MikTeX 2.8 on Vista32). I run the following:

`texify --pdf --clean --tex-option=--output-directory=".." main.tex`

I keep getting an error reading:

`texify: Windows API Error: The system cannot find the file specified`

Things work fine without `--tex-option=--output-directory=".."`. Omitting `--pdf` doesn't improve the situation

Q: How can I get `texify` to place compiled output in the parent directory using the `--tex-option` (or other) switch?

I have very little experience on the command line, so I suspect the answer may be a simple one.

Comment: If instead of using `".."`, you used the full path to the parent directory, does it work?

Comment: Same question but about `latexmk` instead: "[Specify -output-directory when using latexmk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11710/2975)".

Comment: @brianjd Do you use a batch file in order to execute `texify`, or do you call it manually on the command line?

Comment: @diabonas: I'm calling it from the command line

Comment: @Martin: seems that at least with `latexmk` there's a `jobname` switch specifically built to handle this sort of thing. There doesn't seem to be anything like that for `texify`. Guess that's what the `--tex-option` switch is for but it just doesn't seem to be working in my case.

Comment: @Willie: Tried your suggestion. Same error is given.

Comment: @brianjd, did you have any luck solving this problem? The `-I ".."` solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @AliMehrizi: No luck, I believe. It was a while ago. I just let compiled output go to the current directory now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How'bout if you add the switch `-I ".."` to the list of options passed to `texify`? (I'm groping around blindly here because I don't use the util myself.)

The reason for breakage, I think, is that `--tex-option` is only passed to `pdflatex`, which now deposits *all* output files, including the `*.aux` files required to run `bibtex`, in a different directory. So after the first pass, the program tries to run `bibtex` on `main.aux` to resolve any citation references, but since `main.aux` now sits in `../`, it cannot be found and Windows throw an error.

The `-I` switch tells `texify` to search that directory first for input files, at least that's how I read [the manual](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html). So it may help in this instance.

If that doesn't work, your best bet is to write a batch file to first call `texify` and then `mv` the final PDF into the parent directory.

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work. Good suggestion though. It's sounding like writing a batch file is my only option here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 on XP, and with a bit help of your post (I've learned about `--tex-option=` option) I was able to solve my (and yours) problem - use this: `--tex-option="-output-directory=.."` to have output in a parent directory.

Comment: This tex option no longer seems to be supported for texify. Running texify with the option results in : "TeX option "--output-directory" is not supported."

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons it is not possible to write to locations which use a absolute path or includes the parent directory (..). You can change this security setting through an environment variable (I think `MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES=1`) but I advise you strongly not to do it.

Comment: I'm using the `aux-directory` option with a downstream folder, but I still get this error. Any thoughts?