# Texify Output Directory Option

Tags: texify

How can I set the `-output-directory` option in `texify.exe`.

Code below run fine without `-output-directory` option
(purposely splitted the argument for better readability):

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64>texify.exe 
--include-directory="D:\DebuggingUse\TexStudio\latexPDFTesting" 
--job-name="LatexPDF" 
--batch 
--clean 
--max-iterations=2 
--pdf 
--quiet 
"D:\DebuggingUse\TexStudio\latexPDFTesting\document.tex"
```

Code after `-output-directory` added cannot run with error (Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.):

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64>texify.exe 
--include-directory="D:\DebuggingUse\TexStudio\latexPDFTesting" 
--job-name="LatexPDF" 
--batch 
--clean 
--max-iterations=2 
--pdf 
--quiet 
--tex-option=-output-directory="D:\DebuggingUse\TexStudio\latexPDFTesting" 
"D:\DebuggingUse\TexStudio\latexPDFTesting\document.tex"
```

I have tested `--tex-option=-output-directory="samplepath"` and `-output-directory` but with no success.

Thus, is there any other option to specify `output-directory`.

Comment: I never use texify or --output-directory (both for good reasons) but imho it did work once *for relative pathes* so you could try a bug report at the miktex site. It shouldn't work for absolute pathes for security reasons unless you change an environment variable.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, can i know why it shouldn't work for absolute path for what kind of security reason, just out of curiosity? Besides, which environment variable to change if i want to do that?

Comment: Do you want texify to be able to write into /my/other/important/project/folder and perhaps destroy files there? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12453/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thanks for your explanation, so even though i could create a clean folder specifically for Tex output usage, i still shouldn't do it? BTW, currently i am using pdflatex directly to solve this issue as it allows include and output directory.