# How to specify the absolute path of the output directory with latexmk?

Tags: paths, latexmk, centos

I'm trying to execute **latexmk** from my web application and need to specify the path of its output directory. (I'm on Linux CentOS 6.9)

I have my **.tex** files in the directory **/home/(the path)** (this is the absolute path relative to root of the web app) and need to generate the **.pdf** in the same directory with the same name as the original **.tex** file.

The entire command I use goes as follows:

```
latexmk -pdf -jobname=/home/(the path)/filename /home/(the path)/filename.tex
```

This however, does not work; latexmk starts execution and stops with a message

```
I can't write on file filename.aux
```

Instead, if I run a similar command from terminal window with **relative** and not **absolute** paths of the files (suppose I'm in the parent directory of the target folder), such as

```
latexmk -pdf -jobname= target_dir/filename target_dir/filename.tex
```

then it works as expected. Also, skipping the **jobname** and using the absolute path to .tex file works fine, but the problem there is that the output goes into the root directory.

I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11710/specify-output-directory-when-using-latexmk), but still the problem with absolute paths remains.

How is it possible to give the absolute path of the output to latexmk?

Comment: The error message is from pdflatex, not latexmk; latexmk passes the -jobname option to pdflatex, and with the default security settings, an absolute path is prohibited. You can use the -output-directory option instead.  Better still, since the output directory and the document directory are the same, you can use the -cd option to latexmk: `latexmk -cd /home/(the path)/filename.tex`.

Comment: @JohnCollins: thanks a lot! both -output and -cd did the job.

Comment: I'll convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is from `pdflatex`, not `latexmk`. `Latexmk` passes the -jobname option to `pdflatex`, but with the default security settings of TeXLive an absolute path is prohibited.  The accepted answer in the question that is referred to, [Specify -output-directory when using latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11710/specify-output-directory-when-using-latexmk), is actually out of date, and it is the second answer that you should look at.

There are two simple solutions, the first being preferred for the situation in the question.

1. Since your output directory is the same as the document directory, you can use the -cd option: `latexmk -cd /home/(the path)/filename.tex`. 
   This causes `latexmk` to change directory to the document directory before processing the document.
2. You can use the -output-directory option instead, for which an absolute path is permitted:

   `latexmk -output-directory=/home/(the path) /home/(the path)/filename.tex`